# Why does pgfplots give "Dimension too large" error when the "smooth" option is used?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to get an implicit plot using pfgplots, something I've done several times before using code similar to the MWE below. However, this particular plot has been giving me a "Dimension too large" error. After trying many things, I've boiled it down to the use of the "smooth" option.

The following MWE compiles, but the resulting output has a pretty jagged line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis equal image, 
        xmin=-3.5, xmax=3.5, ymin=-3.5, ymax=3.5, 
        view={0}{90}, zmin=-0.1, zmax=0.1, 
    ]
        \addplot3[
            domain=-3.5:3.5, domain y=-3.5:3.5, 
            contour gnuplot={levels={0}, draw color=black, labels=false}, 
            %smooth, 
        ] { 3*x^3 + y^5 - 17*x*y - 1 } ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting plot, but not smooth]

If I uncomment the `%smooth` line above, this gives the "Dimension too large" error, as mentioned above.

My only guess at this point is a bug in the smoothing algorithm used by TikZ/pgfplots. But I can't find anything obvious in the table of points generated by gnuplot that would cause this. For reference, here is that table:

```
# Surface 0 of 1 surfaces

# Curve title: ""MWE_contourtmp0.dat""

# Contour 0, label:        0
-3.5  1.82278  0 
-3.37301  1.74999  0 
-3.20833  1.61636  0 
-2.97478  1.45832  0 
-2.91667  1.40479  0 
-2.625  1.18405  0 
-2.59573  1.16666  0 
-2.33334  0.960836  0 
-2.19565  0.874989  0 
-2.04167  0.75492  0 
-1.76526  0.583323  0 
-1.75  0.571874  0 
-1.45834  0.414449  0 
-1.16881  0.291657  0 
-1.16667  0.290512  0 
-0.875006  0.20224  0 
-0.583341  0.160772  0 
-0.291675  0.216372  0 
-0.212183  0.291657  0 
-0.0965153  0.583323  0 
-0.0333197  0.874989  0 
-8.5e-06  0.961155  0 
 0.0593161  1.16666  0 
 0.228061  1.45832  0 
 0.291657  1.51269  0 
 0.535197  1.74999  0 
 0.583323  1.77426  0 
 0.874989  1.92052  0 
 1.117  2.04165  0 
 1.16666  2.05477  0 
 1.45832  2.11703  0 
 1.74999  2.16045  0 
 2.04165  2.17603  0 
 2.33332  2.15243  0 
 2.62499  2.07511  0 
 2.69382  2.04165  0 
 2.83857  1.74999  0 
 2.7426  1.45832  0 
 2.62499  1.28094  0 
 2.5304  1.16666  0 
 2.33332  0.960705  0 
 2.23013  0.874989  0 
 2.04165  0.714495  0 
 1.84816  0.583323  0 
 1.74999  0.508526  0 
 1.45832  0.335445  0 
 1.35693  0.291657  0 
 1.16666  0.18984  0 
 0.874989  0.0679123  0 
 0.666735 -8.5e-06  0 
 0.583323 -0.0408249  0 
 0.291657 -0.186949  0 
 0.192209 -0.291675  0 
 0.10495 -0.583341  0 
 0.0999931 -0.875006  0 
 0.157375 -1.16667  0 
 0.291657 -1.42993  0 
 0.302608 -1.45834  0 
 0.566325 -1.75  0 
 0.583323 -1.75967  0 
 0.874989 -1.96053  0 
 0.967769 -2.04167  0 
 1.16666 -2.13345  0 
 1.45832 -2.30011  0 
 1.50625 -2.33334  0 
 1.74999 -2.42888  0 
 2.04165 -2.56713  0 
 2.14418 -2.625  0 
 2.33332 -2.68966  0 
 2.62499 -2.8068  0 
 2.85789 -2.91667  0 
 2.91665 -2.93446  0 
 3.20832 -3.03565  0 
 3.49998 -3.15231  0
```

Comment: Probably some implicit divisions by zero happen when using the `smooth` key (near points where the curve has vertical tangent lines). Try `samples=<some larger number>` instead (for example, `samples=101` or `samples=201`).

Comment: FYI, the two points with vertical tangents are `(x,y)=(0.0968113,-0.757445)` and `(x,y)=(2.84857,1.76411)`. So, as an alternative, you may try to split up the x domain `-3.5:3.5` into three parts to avoid getting too close to these points.